# Ajax Auto-Lookup function for text box

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I am designing a php page.In that i have text box.I want autofill (just like google search text box)option for that.I am new to jquery.I am slow in implementing.If anyone knw pls guide me.I want a simple code so that i can paste and check it.I surfed website.All are complex .

Comment: Welcome to SO. I took the liberty of rephrasing your title: Requests for urgent help are not really well received around here. Feel free to roll back if you don't like it

Answer (score 2):

Look at [jQuery Autocomplete Plugin](http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/demo-jquery-autocomplete.html). You can edit the code online to check its behavior.

[Download Page](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/autocomplete.htm)

Comment: I have no options to download

Answer (score 0):

For an input field, you may also need secondary data that can be received from the server.  This tool provides the ability to use that data intuitively.

https://github.com/nfosci/input-fetcher-dropdown